# Pull out array for one key value pair from array of objects and same time filter based on another key value pair

Tags: arrays, object

I have an array of objects like:

```
[{name: "jim", sex:"male"},{name: "june", sex:"female"},{name: "bob", sex:"male"},{name: "janet", sex:"female"},{name: "lisa", sex:"female"},{name: "dave", sex:"male"}];
```

I need to filter for sex=female only and then just return an array of the values from name, like:

```
["june","janet","lisa"]
```

I've looped through and pushed into an array but this is slow, is there a quicker way?

Thanks

Dom

Comment: How "slow" is this?  What language is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Javascript then this is the solution

```
let arr=[{name: "jim", sex:"male"},{name: "june", sex:"female"},{name: "bob", sex:"male"},{name: "janet", sex:"female"},{name: "lisa", sex:"female"},{name: "dave", sex:"male"}];

let result=arr.filter(person => person.sex == "female").map( person => person.name);
```